# How get and show an image through TCP/IP in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, image, sockets, tcp, client

I have a python socket server that sends a PNG file (72755 bytes) whenever receives "send" from the client. The client python code receives 72755 bytes and saves the file correctly:

```py
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    s.send('send')

    f = open('torecv.png','wb')
    l = s.recv(1024)

    while (l):
        f.write(l)
        l = s.recv(1024)
        k = str(l)
        byte_num += len(l)
        if k[-5:-1] == 'done':
            break
    f.write(l[:-4])
    f.close()

    s.close()
```

However, in Swift, the following code gets a total of 72755 bytes and gives me a corrupted PNG file. Can anyone tell me where is the problem? Thank you

```swift
switch client.connect(timeout: 1) {
  case .success:
    switch client.send(string: "send" ) {
      case .success:
        var dataAll : [UInt8] = []
        while true {
            guard let data = client.read(1024, timeout:1) else { break }
            print("bytes: " + String(data.count))
            if String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8) == "done" {
                print("done")
            }else{
                dataAll += data
            }
        }
        print(dataAll.count) // prints 72755
        
        let img : Data = Data(bytes: dataAll, count: dataAll.count)
        writeToFile(data: img, fileName: "testPng")
```

Edit:
The problem could be in saving PNG file (Both Python and Swift get all bytes correctly)

```swift
    func writeToFile(data: Data, fileName: String){
        // get path of directory
        guard let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last else {
            return
        }
        // create file url
        let fileurl =  directory.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).png")
        print(fileurl)
    // if file exists then write data
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileurl.path) {
            if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileurl.path) {
                // seekToEndOfFile, writes data at the last of file(appends not override)
                fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
                fileHandle.write(data)
                fileHandle.closeFile()
                
                var yourImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: fileurl.path)!
                testImg.image = yourImage
                
            }
            else {
                print("Can't open file to write.")
            }
        }
        else {
            // if file does not exist write data for the first time
            do{
                try data.write(to: fileurl, options: .atomic)
            }catch {
                print("Unable to write in new file.")
            }
        }

    }
```

Main Image and what Python gets:

[image]

What Swift gets:

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about python but it looks like you are not increasing K/byte_num by 1024 in the first recv. I mean doesn't it need to add `byte_num += len(l)` before the while loop?

Comment: Not related to your question but you can simply convert bytes to Data like this `let img = Data(dataAll)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are right. Then Python and Swift get the same number of bytes but one is corrupted.

Comment: test it with a really small png, print the bytes and edit your post

Comment: What is the original size of `torecv.png`? Can you post a link to the file? A link to the corrupted one would help as well.

Comment: I was wrong about the number of bytes Python is getting. Both are the same (Thanks to Leo Dabus)

Comment: the second image you have posted is way more than 1024 bytes larger (1,091,765 bytes) against (72,755 bytes). Btw 72,755 bytes it is not corrupted

Comment: I did not check the file size, I just checked the number of received bytes. Then something is wrong with saving the bytes as a PNG file.

Comment: forget about the FileHandle

Comment: try `img.write(to: fileurl, options: .atomic)`

Comment: I found the problem. It kept appending. I removed the png file and it works now. I should first delete the file to recreate it or it appends to the end of it. Thank you. You mentioning the size of the file gave me the hint.

Comment: I was checking the bytes and it was clear that you wrote the same image over and over again to the same file

Comment: No need to delete the file. .atomic will automatically overwrite it.

Comment: Thank you, Leo. ".atomic" did the job.

Comment: you are welcome. if you would like me to write an answer let me know